# How to tell Grails to use Gradle for dependencies resolution

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-plugin, build-dependencies

I'm trying to setup a grails project with gradle but i came a problem, i can't make grails to use gradle for dependencies resolution. If i config the dependencies in gradle build file and run gradle grails-run-app, it always report can't find classes in dependencies jars.

When i cut and paste the dependencies into grails BuildConfig.groovy and everything is ok.

How to tell Grails to use Gradle for dependencies resolution?

I paste my build.gradle file here, Any suggestion?

```
apply plugin: 'grails'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

version "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenRepo urls: 'http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.connorgarvey.gradle:gradle-grails-wrapper:1.0'
    }
}

grails {
    version '2.2.3'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo urls: 'http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/'

}


dependencies {
    compile 'org.modeshape.bom:modeshape-bom-embedded:3.3.0.Final'
    compile 'postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901.jdbc4'
    compile 'javax.jcr:jcr:2.0'
    compile 'org.modeshape:modeshape-jcr:3.3.0.Final'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend using the [grails-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin) instead.

*UPDATED ANSWER, cleanup and usage of bootstrap scope to exclude Tomcat jars from war.*

**General info**

I followed a presentation from Luke Daley (aka *alkemist*) [on Youtube at gr8conf 2013](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FwZvDU2Jeh8). I was able to create a small POC and Gradle seems to work fine with Grails 2.2.3.

**Gradle build file**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/' }
    maven { url 'http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo' }
    maven { url 'http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins' }
    maven { url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release' }
    maven { url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external' }
    maven { url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/release' }
    maven { url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/external' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT',
    'org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.2.3' 
  }
}

version='0.0.1'

apply plugin: 'grails'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/' }
  maven { url 'http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo' }
  maven { url 'http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins' }
  maven { url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release' }
  maven { url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external' }
  maven { url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/release' }
  maven { url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/external' }  
}

grails {
  grailsVersion '2.2.3'
  version '2.2.3'
}

configurations {
  all {
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude module: 'xml-apis'
  }
  test {
    exclude module: 'groovy-all'
  }
  compile {
    exclude module: 'hibernate'
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile( "org.grails:grails-crud:$grails.grailsVersion",
           'org.grails:grails-gorm:1.3.7')

  bootstrap "org.grails:grails-plugin-tomcat:$grails.grailsVersion"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send a text.... ;) Kidding.

> You must include a version of the 'grails-bootstrap' artifact in the
>   'classpath' configuration. You should also add whichever Grails
>   artifacts you need. 'grails-crud' and 'grails-gorm' will give you
>   everything you need for a standard Grails web application.

Have a look at the [plugin docs](https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin).

Comment: Thanks for the response, i didn't use gradle-grails-plugin, because this plugin didn't work with gradle 1.6 and grails 2.2.3. It always report my grails version is 2.2.3 and required version is 1.4.3 please upgrade grails. So i turn to gradle-grails-wrapper.

Comment: Details error message. Application expects grails version [2.2.3], but GRAILS_HOME is version [1.3.4] - use the correct Grails version or run 'grails upgrade' if this Grails version is newer than the version your application expects.

Comment: @user2478308 Do you have GRAILS_HOME set to 1.3.4 in classpath variables?